# Automate WhatsApp with Python & store WhatsApp login

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp

I am trying to automate `WhatsApp`. I use selenium but the issue is that I have to scan `QRCode` every time I launch a `chrome instance`. I tried by saving the `cookies` of logged browser and then load the `cookies` but it didn't work and still show the `QRcode` to sign in.

I wanted to store `WhatsApp login` so that I don't have to log in every time I run the script.

Is this something possible with `Selenium` or if there is another better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add chrome profile , that will allows reusing session data:

```
chrom_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
```

**To get user data drectory:**

**open** : chrome://version in address bar

[image]

copy till user data don't need profile part

Answer (score 0):

To store WhatsApp login u have to open chrome in debug mode. following procedure i used in windows and it works.

first add chrome.exe in environment variable. then open chrome in debug mode from cmd. I use following vbscript to open chrome in debug mode. you can just save the code snip as chrome_launch.vbs and use this script to lauch chrome, only first time u would be asked for scan qr code.

```
Set objStdOut = WScript.StdOut
set osh = createObject("Wscript.shell")
user_profile = """C:\Users\" & osh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%") & "\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\selenium_chrome_profile"""
osh.run "cmd /c " & "chrome.exe https://web.whatsapp.com/ --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=" & user_profile, 0, True
set osh = Nothing
```

after login whatsapp web, used following python snip to attach with existing session

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
```